# Where does one go to school to be in a space program?

Tags: mars, nasa, astronauts, training

I am interested into going to college. What school or degree should I take to get a seat in the Mars missions? Space Camp?

Which school has the highest student to space program statistic?

Comment: [This school](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) might be a good idea to visit first. This is a text-book definition of a question who's answer is primarily opinion-based, and so will be quickly closed.

Comment: Space Camp? No. You need to get a very serious degree from a very serious college or university. Your best bets by far are the US Naval Academy and the US Air Force Academy. (West Point also is a good choice.) Other than those military academies, you should look at the very few top schools in aerospace engineering: MIT, Stanford, Purdue, Georgia Tech, the universities of Colorado, Texas, Washington, Michigan, plus a few others. Ivy League schools are another good choice. If you're 12, now is a good time to start planning to attend one of those schools. If you're 16, it's probably too late.

Comment: @DavidHammen I see some "space stuff" at Johns Hopkins (e.g. Parker Solar Probe)

Comment: One of the schools @DavidHammen mentioned, Purdue, has a disproportionate number of NASA astronauts from there, along with many engineers working in the program (I didn't go there but worked with many who did)

Comment: @uhoh - That's the Applied Physics Lab, an offshoot of Johns Hopkins (I worked there several decades ago, and took some graduate classes while I was there). Maybe my google fu is lacking this evening, but the only astronaut I could find who received a degree from Johns Hopkins is Gregory R. Wiseman. But that's a master's degree. His undergrad is from RPI, which boasts four astronauts. I intentionally left graduate schools out of my list because (a) The Naval Post Graduate School outranks all of them, by far, and (b) one step at at time.

Comment: Speaking of one step at a time, Eagle Scouts are thick as thieves in the Astronaut Office. (The Girl Scout equivalent, the Gold Award, is also quite well represented there.) [More than two-thirds of all current and former astronauts have been involved in scouting.](https://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/informal/features/F_NASA_and_Scouting.html) If you're **ten**, now is a good time to start thinking about working toward Eagle / the Gold Award. If you're fourteen and haven't started yet, it's probably too late.

Comment: @DavidHammen now that BSA is transitioning to less rigid gender rules, perhaps Eagle will be available without restriction in the future.